How to have non-italic text from \cite[]{} within theorem using amsthm and article class?
I have a tex file:
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,enumitem,mathtools,fullpage,microtype}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\setlist{font=\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{assumption} \label{main_assmpt1}
There exist constants $C>0, \alpha \in (0, 1), \beta \in (0, 1)$ such that for $t \in \TT$ and $x, y \in \RR^d$:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]
\item $\nu$ has a density $\ell_\nu \in C^\alpha_b (\RR^d)$.
\item $a_t$ is invertible.
\end{enumerate}
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
Let \cref{main_assmpt1} hold.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \cite[Theorem 2.1]{mckean1966class} ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{mckean1966class}
Henry~P McKean~Jr.
\newblock A class of markov processes associated with nonlinear parabolic
  equations.
\newblock {\em Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  56(6):1907--1911, 1966.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

I particularly like the non-italic quoted theorem name:

When I change from \documentclass[11pt]{amsart} to \documentclass[11pt]{article}, I lost this desired appearance:

Could you explain how to keep this aesthetic feature within the class article?

BTW: Because this is at least your second question about switching from amsart to article, but keeping the output of amsart: Why not using amsart, if you want the result of amsart?

@cabohah Could you elaborate more on which "additional changes are needed"? For your second comment, it's just for my curiosity...

@cabohah I included package amsthm in my MWE, no?

Oh, sorry, yes. Strange, my immediate copy, after you've posted the question, did not have it. I'm sure there was an error and I've also not removed it in my test file. Nevertheless: The MWE should show the issue, not only the expected result.

amsart uses:
\def\@citestyle{\m@th\upshape\mdseries}
\let\citeform\@firstofone
\def\@cite#1#2{{%
  \@citestyle[\citeform{#1}\if@tempswa, #2\fi]}}

to explicitly set cites \upshape. The default LaTeX cite command does not do something like this. The default \@cite definition of LaTeX is:
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}

So inside a theorem the theorem body font is used for the cite, too. But you can redefine it similar, by coping the amsart code:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,enumitem,mathtools,fullpage,microtype}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\setlist{font=\normalfont}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\makeatletter
\def\@citestyle{\m@th\upshape\mdseries}
\let\citeform\@firstofone
\def\@cite#1#2{{%
  \@citestyle[\citeform{#1}\if@tempswa, #2\fi]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{assumption} \label{main_assmpt1}
There exist constants $C>0, \alpha \in (0, 1), \beta \in (0, 1)$ such that for $t \in \TT$ and $x, y \in \RR^d$:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]
\item $\nu$ has a density $\ell_\nu \in C^\alpha_b (\RR^d)$.
\item $a_t$ is invertible.
\end{enumerate}
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
Let \cref{main_assmpt1} hold.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \cite[Theorem 2.1]{mckean1966class} ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{mckean1966class}
Henry~P McKean~Jr.
\newblock A class of markov processes associated with nonlinear parabolic
  equations.
\newblock {\em Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
56(6):1907--1911, 1966.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}


Notes:

The code above works if you really make your bibliography manually. If you use a package like biblatex, please see the manual of that package for more information about formatting of cites. And yes, I would recommend to use such a package, i.e., biblatex.

If want not only the cites but also the rest of the theorem body to not use an italic shape, you should use either \newtheoremstyle to define a corresponding style, or use, e.g., \theoremstyle{definition}.

If you, e.g., use natbib you can instead use something like \bibpunct{\upshape\mdseries[}{]}{,}{n}{}{,}. See the natbib manual for more information about \bibpunct.



Thank you very much for your elaboration! Unfortunately, Elsevier requires natlib and not biblatex for its journals.

@Akira You mean natbib? natbib also has its own definition of \@cite depending on options. So the code in this answer IMHO would not help. This is, why I always say: The MWE should show the real usage case. If you use a bibliography package and have a question about bibliography you should show a MWE using this package. Not doing so, very often wastes your time and also the time of the helpers. :(

The command \bibpunct{\upshape\mdseries[}{]}{,}{n}{}{,} works great when I use \usepackage[compress]{natbib} in my memoir class.
